# Rescatar base de datos

Tags: mysql

Trabajando en un proyecto de base de datos se me daño el disco duro del PC, lo saque del PC y lo conecte como un disco externo y así se pueden ver todos los archivos, es posible rescatar las bases de datos que están en el disco? Como  se haría?

Comment: Como tal, si puedes acceder al directorio del servidor de MySQL, verás varios archivos con el nombre de las tablas que tenías. Es cuestión de copiarlas. Luego en un servidor ya funcionando bien, copias esas tablas. Lo único que tendrás que miras si copiar las tablas de sistema.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes de hacer es buscar la carpeta donde estaba instalada `mysql`.

En mi caso por ejemplo utilizo windows con xampp, entonces mis bases de datos se encuentran en el directorio:

`C:\xampp\mysql\data`

Dentro de dicho directorio existen carpetas con los respectivos nombres de las base de datos, esas carpetas son las base de datos.

Ahora lo que se debe de hacer es copiar dichas carpetas y llevarlas a un directorio similar y podras verlas en un `php-admin` sin ningun problema.

Comment: Si @Shassain, el nombre de las bases de datos y sus tablas se ven, pero al consultarlas o ver la estructura realmente no existen, aparecen con mensaje "Tables could not be fetched"

Comment: @JuanCarlos, Pues dicho mensaje puede deberse a que las versiones de sql no son las mismas. Es decir tenias una version en la PC que se te quemo y otra en la actual en la que tratas de recuperar.

Comment: @JuanCarlos, tambien puede ser  que necesite algunas dependencias, lo que puedes hacer es copiar toda la carpeta `data`  y reemplazarlo por el que tienes. Claro esto siempre y cuando tu base de datos este vacio o sea nueva.

Comment: Mira, dentro del nuevo directorio data se borra todo menos el directorio MySQL y se copian todas los directorios menos el directorio MySQL del viejo data y ya, funciona si la versión de MySQL es la misma, en mi caso aplica y funciono a la perfección. gracias a todos por su orientación